# What does i << 1 mean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I was going through some code for prime numbers on Stack and found this.

I tried experimenting with this for sometime and figured this :

```
var i = 5;
var j = 0;
```

If i write 
       j = i << 1, all it does is assigns (i * 2) ie - 10 in this case to j

If i write 
       j = i << 2, (i * 2) * 2 ie - 10 * 2 .....and so on.

Now i have a doubt what actually this operator does ?

I tried googling this, but did not find any straight solution to this.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao — Java and JavaScript are not the same thing (like Car and Carpet are not the same thing).

Comment: please do your research (google) before hitting stackoverflow.

Comment: @Quentin : They are exactly the same things as far as this operator is concerned.

Comment: @Harsh — But pointing to documentation for a different programming language without explaining that they work in the same way is a good way to confuse people.

Comment: yeah, point taken. although Car and Carpet??? i don... Oh... now i get it!!! NICE :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are [Bitwise Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) in Javascript.

*Bitwise operators treat their operands as a sequence of 32 bits (zeros and ones), rather than as decimal, hexadecimal, or octal numbers. For example, the decimal number nine has a binary representation of 1001. Bitwise operators perform their operations on such binary representations, but they return standard JavaScript numerical values.*

**Left Shift Operator :**

a << b  : *Shifts a in binary representation b (< 32) bits to the left, shifting in zeros from the right.*

Comment: I want to add, they do the same thing in PHP.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the left operand is converted an int32, and the right operand is converted to a uint32 before the operation is performed, per the [spec](http://es5.github.io/#x11.7.1).

Answer (score 1):

`<<` is the left shift operator. Each bit would shift left the number of times specified. Example: `n<<2` would bitwise shift `n` 2 times, adding zeros to the right.

```
n=4  // 0000 0000 0000 0100
n<<2 //<= 0000 0000 0001 0000 - Value is 16
```

Answer (score 0):

[The `<<` operator<sup>[ES5 spec]</sup>](http://es5.github.io/#x11.7.1) is the left bit shift operator. It takes the number on the left and shifts the bits as many places as the number on the right. `i << 2`, for example, will shift the digits of `i` to the left 2 places.

```
var i = 5;  // i: 0000 0000 0000 0101
i = i << 2; // i: 0000 0000 0001 0100
```